# Prove that the derivative of an even differentiable function is odd, and the derivative of an odd is even.

Tags: limits, derivatives

Prove that the derivative of an even differentiable function is odd, and the derivative of an odd differentiable function is even.

Here are my workings so far.

> Lets prove the derivative of an odd differentiable function is even first. Let the odd function be $f(x)$. We have $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a^-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$
>
> $$f'(-x)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {-f(x-h)+f(x)}{h}$$

And so, I am stuck. Thanks in advance. Hints are appreciated. Solutions are even more welcome!

Comment: I noticed you put $x\to h$ where you needed $h\to 0$, so I fixed that. You must be confounding two different definitions for the derivative.

Comment: Why don't you differenciate the equality $f(-x) = -f(x)$ using the chain rule? No need to come back to the definition of the derivative with the limits.

Comment: That's true! Thanks. Now I know a lot of ways to do this. But I was wondering how do I approach it from this definition angle?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Continuing from your last line, 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} -\frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}=f'(x) 
$$

That completes the proof for $f$ an odd function.

The analogous approach will probably work for $f(x)$ an even function.

$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}=-f'(x) 
$$

Comment: I don't understand how $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}=f'(x)$ Isn't the definition of $ f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{-h}$ The difference between the -h and the +h

Comment: They are equivalent: you can just write $-h=h'$ and note that $h'$ goes to zero as $-h$ goes to zero. That's a formal trick, but you should think a little about the picture that goes along with the derivative to see why the negative sign doesn't matter.

Comment: I see. That was helpful!

Answer (score 13):

If $f(x)$ is odd then,$$f'(x)=\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}=\frac{d(-f(-x))}{dx}=-\frac{d(f(-x))}{dx}=-(-f'(-x))=f'(-x)$$

Here,  have used $\frac{d(f(-x))}{dx}=-f'(-x)$ (using chain rule)

You can follow similar approach for even $f(x)$

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to do this using $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h}$?

Comment: @SingaporeanDude. If you want to see that, it's in my solution. I like this solution better though!

Comment: For odd $f(x)$, you can do like this : $$f'(-x)= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(-x+h)-f(-x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {-f(x-h)+f(x)}{h}
\lim_{h\to 0} -\frac {f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}=f'(x) 
$$