# $g$ is any even differentiable function defined for all real numbers , prove that $\frac{dg}{dx}$ is an odd function.

Tags: limits, derivatives

> > Question: Suppose that $g$ is any even differentiable function defined for all real numbers (not necessarily a polynomial).
> >
> > Prove that $\frac{dg}{dx}$ is an odd function.

[I have seen this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203949/prove-that-the-derivative-of-an-even-differentiable-function-is-odd-and-the-der) but I want help on the specific part I am stuck on

---

What I have attempted (my two attempts) :

**First attempt**

Consider the definition of a derivative:
   $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

If g(x) is a function which is even then $g(-x)=g(x)$ and $g(x-h) = g(-x+h)$

$$g'(x) \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{g(-x+h)-g(-x)}{h}$$

$$g'(x) \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x-h)-g(x)}{h}$$

Now I am stuck trying to deduce the deriviative

---

**Second attempt**

Consider a function $g(x)$ which is even then $g(x) = g(-x)$ then

$$ g'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[g(-x)] $$

Then by chain rule

$$ g'(x) = -g'(-x) $$

but if a function is odd $f(-x)=-f(x)$

$$ g'(x) = -(-g'(x)) $$

$$ g'(x) = g'(x) $$

This is not correct but where did I go wrong?

Comment: Hint: since $h$ is approaching $0$ from either side, you can effectively replace $h$ with $-h$ in the limit (or, if you prefer, let $h_2 = -h$).

Comment: dude second attempt is 100% correct. just check the domain to be symmetric and from the problem we get that the domain is whole real line so all good. i don't get what's wrong with that. it's totally correct

Comment: On your second attempt, after doing the chain rule, sub in -x for x. Your problem is you assume g' is odd when you're supposed to be proving it, which you're only one step away from.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald I think i am wrong because I have not proven the derivative is a odd function? that is why

Comment: @Kaynex wait why can i sub in -x for x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First attempt:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$
Let's assume $f$ is even. Subbing in -x for x:
$$f'(-x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(-x + h) - f(-x)}{h}$$
$$f'(-x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x - h) - f(x)}{h}$$
Make the substitution w = -h:
$$f'(-x) = \lim_{w\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + w) - f(x)}{-w}$$
$$f'(-x) = -f'(x)$$
Second attempt:
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}[f(-x)]$$
$$f'(x) = -f'(-x)$$
Letting x be -x:
$$f'(-x) = -f'(x)$$

Comment: Hey , sorry for repeating my question but why can x be replaced with -x?

Comment: Remember that x is a placeholder for, well, anything. We can also let x be $x^2$ if we wanted. That wouldn't help here though.

Comment: Ah I see , thank you !