# Boundedness of $n^{th}$ derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x) =\arctan(x) $ then the sequence {$f^n(0) $} is bounded for all positive even integers n ?

What i have think
denominator  of first derivative you can see that i will never attain zero moreover which is a cts function and any nth derivative will be of higher order than the numerator .. so it will be bounded

Comment: $\arctan$? That's an odd function, isn't it?

Comment: yes, so how does it help?

Comment: What is a *cts* function? If this means *continuous*, please take the time to write out the word. Otherwise, you should explain what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand to Taylor series:
$$y=\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\cdots$$
$$y'=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots$$
$$y''=-2x+4x^3-6x^5+\cdot$$
$$y'''=-2+12x^2-30x^4+\cdots$$
$$\cdots$$

Thus:
$$y^{(2n)}(0)=0, n\ge 2$$
$$y^{(2n+1)}(0)=(-1)^n(2n)!, n\ge 1$$

Comment: You should have a $(-1)^n$ factor in the last line.

Comment: @Bernard, thank you. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Derivative of odd function is even and derivative of even function is odd,for the proof of this take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203949/prove-that-the-derivative-of-an-even-differentiable-function-is-odd-and-the-der)